# NumPy: How to obtain all elements adjacent to certain elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume that we have an [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) of elements. When [flattened](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), it's guaranteed to be one-dimensional. I'm looking for a way via [NumPy API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/index.html), without using loops, to obtain elements adjacent to a certain element (or a set of elements), if these exist, from that flattened ndarray.

Below is my way to achieve this in loops, but this is highly inefficient, so I'm looking for more NumPy-ish solutions.

```
import numpy as np

def find_adjacent(v,a,side={'L','R','B'}):
    # v is a 1d vector which is the aforementioned flattened ndarray.
    # a is a 1d array of elements which must be adjacent to the chosen.
    # side is either L (consider only elements adjacent to the left)
    #                R (consider only elements adjacent to the right)
    #                B (consider only elements adjacent to the left and to the right)

    result = np.array([])
    for i in range(v.size):
        if (side == 'L' or side == 'B') and i < a.size:
            continue
        elif (side == 'R' or side == 'B') and v.size-i < a.size:
            continue
        elif side == 'L':
            if np.array_equal(v[i-a.size:i], a):
                np.append(result,v[i])
        elif side == 'R':
            if np.array_equal(v[i+1:i+a.size], a):
                np.append(result,v[i])
        elif side == 'B':
            if np.array_equal(v[i+1:i+a.size], a) and np.array_equal(v[i-a.size:i], a):
                np.append(result,v[i])

    return result
```

The question is, how to achieve the same result without using loops? Does it get easier if instead of an array `a` will be a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def find_adjacent(v, a, side):
   if side=='L':
      return v[np.isin(np.roll(v,1),a)]
   elif side=='R':
      return v[np.isin(np.roll(v,-1),a)]
   else:
      return v[np.isin(np.roll(v,1),a) & np.isin(np.roll(v,-1),a)]
```

Depending on what you meant by "only adjacent to the left and to the right", you way want to replace the `&` of the last line by a `|`. With `&` you list elements of `v` whose both neighbors are in `a`. With `|` you list elements of `v` whose either neighbors are in `a`.

Also, you may also want to swap `L` and `R` if by "only element adjacent to the left" you meant that you want to list elements of v that are on the left of an element of a; or to list elements of v whose element on the left is in a (which sounds similar, but one is the opposite of the other)

And, last note: with `np.roll`, that means that the last element of v is considered adjacent with the first.
So, if not wanted (which is likely, from your description of the problem. But I try always to keep my first version as simple as possible, and complexify it step by step. Here, to focus first on the main idea: `np.roll/np.isin`), you can just remove the element that went the other side. Like this:

```py
def find_adjacent(v, a, side):
   left=np.roll(v,1)
   left[0]=None # or any value that should match nothing
   right=np.roll(v,-1)
   right[-1]=None
   if side=='L':
      return v[np.isin(left,a)]
   elif side=='R':
      return v[np.isin(right,a)]
   else:
      return v[np.isin(left,a) & np.isin(right,a)]
```